# Markov property on non-stationary time-series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, markov-process

I am working with a dataset with several time-series, and I want to test the Markov property on all of them. However, some of them are non-stationary and following the definitions on the text "Testing for the Markov Property in Time Series" from Chen and Hong, the beginning of the theoretical description is

"Suppose ${X_t}$ is a strictly stationary $d$-dimensional time series process, where $d$
is a positive integer. It follows a Markov process if the conditional probability
distribution of $X_{t+1}$ given the information set $I_t = \{X_t , X_{t−1} , ...\}$ is the same
as the conditional probability distribution of $X_{t+1}$ given $X_t$ only."

So my question is: can the Markov property hold for a non-stationary time series? If the answer is positive, how could I test it on my non-stationary data?

Comment: Can you give some more details? Is $X_t$ a continuous variable? Observed at equidistant points? ...

Comment: In what way are they non-stationary?

Comment: $X_t$ is a continuous variable observed daily for 15 years. It does not pass the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test for stationarity nor can it be detrended with simple differentiation.